# WCF with authorize can't find the custom validate function

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

I create a service with this property :

```
namespace WcfServiceLibrary1
{

    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string GetProductName(int productID);

        [OperationContract]
        int GetProductQty(int productID);

        [OperationContract]
        string GetCategoryName(int productID);

        // TODO: Add your service operations here
    }


}
```

I should implement an authorize function as you can see here :

```
namespace WcfServiceLibrary1
{
    public class CustomValidator : UserNamePasswordValidator
   {
       public override void Validate(string userName, string password)
       {
           if (userName == "test" && password == "test")
               return;
           throw new SecurityTokenException(
               "Unknown Username or Password");
       }
    }
}
```

In `appsetting` i define the `Behavior` and other properties of the validate function as you can see here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's 
  app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WcfServiceLibrary1.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="WcfServic">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress = "http://localhost:8733/WcfServiceLibrary1.Service1.svc" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <!-- Service Endpoints -->
        <!-- Unless fully qualified, address is relative to base address supplied above -->
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SafeServiceConf" contract="WcfServiceLibrary1.IService1">
          <!-- 
              Upon deployment, the following identity element should be removed or replaced to reflect the 
              identity under which the deployed service runs.  If removed, WCF will infer an appropriate identity 
              automatically.
          -->
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <!-- Metadata Endpoints -->
        <!-- The Metadata Exchange endpoint is used by the service to describe itself to clients. --> 
        <!-- This endpoint does not use a secure binding and should be secured or removed before deployment -->
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>

      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WcfServic">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <serviceCredentials>
            <userNameAuthentication
                 userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom"
                 customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="WcfServiceLibrary1.CustomValidator.Validate,WcfServiceLibrary1"
                                                                      />
          </serviceCredentials>
        </behavior>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
          set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" httpsGetEnabled="True"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
          set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
          to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
        </behavior>

      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="SafeServiceConf" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536">
          <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="65536" maxArrayLength="65536"
          maxBytesPerRead="65536" />
          <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

In this part i define the custom function to authorize

```
 <serviceCredentials>
                <userNameAuthentication
                     userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom"
                     customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="WcfServiceLibrary1.CustomValidator.Validate,WcfServiceLibrary1"
                                                                          />
              </serviceCredentials>
```

But when i run the service i got this error :

```
System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'WcfServiceLibrary1.CustomValidator.Validate' from assembly 'WcfServiceLibrary1'.
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMarkHandle stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName, ObjectHandleOnStack type)
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName)
   at System.RuntimeType.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Type.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError)
   at System.ServiceModel.Configuration.UserNameServiceElement.ApplyConfiguration(UserNamePasswordServiceCredential userName)
   at System.ServiceModel.Configuration.ServiceCredentialsElement.ApplyConfiguration(ServiceCredentials behavior)
   at System.ServiceModel.Configuration.ServiceCredentialsElement.CreateBehavior()
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ConfigLoader.LoadBehaviors[T](ServiceModelExtensionCollectionElement`1 behaviorElement, KeyedByTypeCollection`1 behaviors, Boolean commonBehaviors)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ConfigLoader.LoadServiceDescription(ServiceHostBase host, ServiceDescription description, ServiceElement serviceElement, Action`1 addBaseAddress, Boolean skipHost)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.LoadConfigurationSectionInternal(ConfigLoader configLoader, ServiceDescription description, ServiceElement serviceSection)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.ApplyConfiguration()
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost.ApplyConfiguration()
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.InitializeDescription(UriSchemeKeyedCollection baseAddresses)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost.InitializeDescription(Type serviceType, UriSchemeKeyedCollection baseAddresses)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost..ctor(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)
   at Microsoft.Tools.SvcHost.ServiceHostHelper.CreateServiceHost(Type type, ServiceKind kind)
   at Microsoft.Tools.SvcHost.ServiceHostHelper.OpenService(ServiceInfo info)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line  in your config doesnt look right. `customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="WcfServiceLibrary1.CustomValidator.Validate,WcfServiceLibrary1"`

`WcfServiceLibrary1.CustomValidator.Validate` is a method but it expects a type hence its trying to instantiate Validate. Try replacing it with

`customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="WcfServiceLibrary1.CustomValidator,WcfServiceLibrary1"`